# Configure GIT_EDITOR for Windos

Tags: windows-7, git

I am a beginner using GIT. I installed GIT on my Windows-7 PC and make the first steps.

The command `git commit -v` allows to edit the commit message with an editor before doing the actual commit. I don't want to use this VI-style thing in the command line. Therefore I configured

```
export GIT_EDITOR=notepad
```

But alas, th Windows notepad can't handle this LF only file. So I wan to use an editor that can do it like Notepad++. I configured

```
export GIT_EDITOR=/c/Progra~2/Notepa~1/Notepa~1
```

and Notepad++ is started. Previous tries used the `Program\ Files` syntax, but GIT failed to open the program. But there is a problem, it complains about a missing file:

```
Create new file
c:\Users\Harper\Documents\Experiments\git\$@ doesn't exist. Create it?
```

Is there a plain way to get rid of this VI-style prog? How do I configure so that it can be used on Windows-7?

Comment: The answer is on StackOverflow:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10564/how-can-i-set-up-an-editor-to-work-with-git-on-windows

Comment: Please read [Can I answer my own question?](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Yes, I've read. And yes, I did answer my own question. The StackExchange software decided that the answer was too short and converted it to a comment. I hesitate to add noise stuff to overcome the "too sort hurdle".